# How to set Tkinter Message widget background to transparent

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a Tkinter window that only displays a message. Is there any way to make everything but the message transparent, so that only the message is displayed.
Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
root= tkr.Tk()
root.wm_attributes("-alpha",self.transparency)
root.overrideredirect(1)
message = tkr.Message(root,'blabla')
message.config(font = ('times', 100, 'italic'))
message.pack()
```

Comment: Pick one from [`[python][tkinter] transparent`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+transparent)